# Why is Facebook debugger ignoring my request to scrape again?

Tags: video, youtube, facebook-debugger

I have a [YouTube video](https://youtu.be/NHBDXtn7pjA) that I would like to post on Facebook, but it keeps showing an old thumbnail that I changed 2 weeks ago. I tried to you Facebook Debugger, gave the link, and ask to scrape again. But it still shows the same old thumbnail.

Is there a trick to force Facebook Debugger to REALLY scrape again?